# How can i reference an exe written with c/c++ to a c# project?

Tags: c#, c++, c, .net, com

I have a camera SDK that was created with the C language that I would like to call from a .NET application.

Our main project is written with the .NET framework.  We are trying to integrate the camera SDK with the .NET project. The SDK provides some DLLs, but I am getting a COM (common object model) error when I attempt to reference it.

We could not solve this directly, and after that I tried to create a DLL interface between .h and c# DLL files but i received the same COM error. Also, the SDK provides some samples for programming the cameras (ex:Search for IP-connected cameras) but a reference to the .EXE does not work and I get a COM error.

Comment: @OP - I edited your question to enhance English readability. Please look over my edit and be sure that I did not change the intent of your question.

Comment: Import the type library into your project. If the component lives in an .exe, there should be a .tlb file along with it.

Comment: @xxbbcc Component lives in .EXE but there is no type library in files. Can be files are corrupted ore someting.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking. Tell us what COM problems/Errors you get! Tell us what you already done. Improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good article on Microsoft's site on how to call a Native DLL from managed code:  [How to: Call Native DLLs from Managed Code Using PInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-call-native-dlls-from-managed-code-using-pinvoke)

It should at least get you started down your path.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @user4581301.  I should have done a better job with that link.